# Should livedata be always used in ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

It seems like [recommended](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) pattern for fields in viewmodel is:

```
val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

fun select(item: Item) {
    selected.value = item
}
```

(btw, is it correct that the `selected` field isn't private?)

But what if I don't need to subscribe to the changes in the ViewModel's field. I just need passively pull that value in another fragment.

My project details:

- one activity and a bunch of simple fragments replacing each other with the navigation component
- ViewModel does the business logic and carries some values from one fragment to another
- there is one ViewModel for the activity and the fragments, don't see the point to have more than one ViewModel, as it's the same business flow
- I'd prefer to store a value in one fragment and access it in the next one which replaces the current one instead of pass it into a bundle and retrieve again and again manually in each fragment

ViewModel:

```
private var amount = 0
fun setAmount(value: Int) { amount = value}
fun getAmount() = amount
```

Fragment1:

```
bnd.button10.setOnClickListener { viewModel.setAmount(10) }
```

Fragment2:

```
if(viewModel.getAmount() < 20) { bnd.textView.text = "less than 20" }
```

Is this would be a valid approach? Or there is a better one? Or should I just use LiveData or Flow?

Maybe I should use `SavedStateHandle`? Is it injectable in ViewModel?

Comment: do you store the values in the viewmodel or do you retrieve them from disk/database/api etc? If it's all in memory then I wouldn't use LiveData at all, and as you share ViewModel between fragments I would just use regular variables/functions. In case some operations take longer I would use suspend functions

Comment: `btw, is it correct that the selected field isn't private?` completely depends on what it's used for.

Comment: @Stachu, no, no long taking operations, storing in-memory within the lifecycle

Comment: @a_local_nobody, can you please elaborate regarding that MutableLiveData field is not private in the case? Don't see the point to have the `select(item: Item)` method if `selected` is public anyways

Comment: `can you please elaborate regarding that...` no, i can't, because this is the only code you've posted :) that was the point of my first comment - if there's a _reason_ to make it public, then make it public, if there isn't, then you can make it private. don't over complicate it. there's nothing _wrong_ with it being public (your code will compile perfectly fine) but if it isn't going to be used, you can make it private _perhaps_

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question,

**No**, It is not mandatory to use LiveData always inside ViewModel, it is just an observable pattern to inform the caller about updates in data.
If you have something which won't be changed frequently and can be accessed by its instance. You can completely ignore wrapping it inside LiveData.
And anyways ViewModel instance will be preserved and so are values inside it.

And regarding private field, `MutableLiveData` should never be exposed outside the class, as the data flow is always from VM -> View which is beauty of MVVM pattern

```
private val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()
val selectedLiveData : LiveData<Item>
    get() = selected

fun select(item: Item) {
    selected.value = item
}
```

Comment: `as the data flow is always from VM -> View`, but in your code snippet data also flows from View to VM via the `select(item: Item)` method, isn't it?

Comment: It is not data flow, you are calling the function, data is only updated inside VM.